# changing more tag default value

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blogg where i want to change the value of the "more" tag. I tried to change "the content" code that is in the post but that wont work.

I have tried to look trough every file i can find without managing to change the value that is "read more..".

When i look in the sourcecode i can se this

```
"class="more-link">(mer&hellip;)</a></p>"
```

Anyone got any ide where i could change it ? right now i do not know what i should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```